# $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ is differentiable in $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Define a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$  if $x\neq0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x=0$. I want to show that $g$ is two times differentiable and i want to compute $g'(0)$ and $g''(0)$. Can someone help me with this? Can you do something with L'Hospital? since both functions are differentiable? Or do you have to do something more basically? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: What do you know about power series? Do you know the Taylor/MacLaurin series of $\sin$?

Comment: You can't use l'Hospital rule as it requires differentiability, and you don't know yet if the function actually is differentiable. You would better use the differentiability definition: the function has a derivative in $x=0$ [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if)...? Try it and show your progress.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to consider
$$
G(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin x}{x} & \text{if $x\ne0$}\\[6px]
1 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
because $g(x)=G(\pi x)$ and $g$ is (twice) differentiable if and only if $G$ is.

The function $G$ is continuous at $0$, by a well known limit. The derivative, for $x\ne0$, is
$$
G'(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}G'(x)=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2))-x+\frac{1}{6}x^3+o(x^3)}{x^2}=0
$$
Thus $G$ is differentiable at $0$, by l'Hôpital. Consequently, $g'(0)=\pi G'(0)=0$.

Can you compute the second derivative and argue similarly?

---

There's an alternative way, with Taylor expansion:
$$
\sin(\pi x)=\pi x-\frac{\pi^3 x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)
$$
so
$$
g(x)=1-\frac{\pi^2 x^2}{6}+o(x^2)
$$
so (in a neighborhood of $0$),
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{\pi^2 x}{3}+o(x)
$$
and
$$
g''(x)=-\frac{\pi^2}{3}+o(1)
$$
so $g''(0)=-\pi^2/3$.

Comment: I think the second derivative in $0$ is equal to $-\pi^2/3$. Is this correct?

Comment: @SonyaWatkins Yes; I added an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

At zero, the function is continuous and you can use the bilateral definition of the first derivative,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}.$$

As the function is even, the limit is $0$.

Then,

$$f''(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-2f(0)+f(-h)}{h^2}=2\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi h)-\pi h}{\pi h^3}=-2\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\pi^2\sin(\pi h)}{6\pi h}=-\frac{\pi^2}3,$$

applying L'Hospital twice.